# Is it possible to get value of height or width of cell in worksheet of xlswriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have problem because xlswriter has only setters - I cannot find any getters in documentation.

I would like to get property of some cell but don't know how to access it.

Comment: It isn't possible to read Excel metrics using XlsxWriter. What exactly are you trying to do?